# What is the difference between REM and single quotation mark?

Tags: .net, vb.net, comments

I saw this odd REM Statement in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzw0d942.aspx) and wondered why this statement even exists and what is the difference between `REM` and `'`?

Comment: Just [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzw0d942.aspx)...no differences.

Comment: Then why they even made it?

Comment: Heritage of old days...BASIC had REM but it's pretty verbose so they introduced single quotation mark

Comment: @Agel That's a question to microsoft, not us! We can't answer it.

Comment: It's all for backward compatibility with very early versions of Basic. There's much stranger stuff than REM still in VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is about 19 years, give or take.  REM comes from 1964, Dartmouth College where the language was invented.

It got really popular in the mid 1970s, a good fit for the rather underpowered micro-computers of that era.  Often supplied with their Basic implementation by Microsoft, it was their first real product.  They extended it significantly from the fairly hokey Dartmouth version.  The single-quote comment was added at least in their 1983 GW-Basic version.  For an underpowered micro-computer named the IBM-PC.

Otherwise means the exact same thing.  I'd guess at it being favored for making comments more readable without the distraction of a keyword.  The guarantee that a single-quote key was actually available might have had something to do with it as well.  Guesses, this is too long ago.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing different between REM and '; it is just MS's none-documented upgrade to the rest of the world.